# Set min/max on TextField type="number"?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, redux-form

I'm using Material-UI v1.0.0-beta23 along with `redux-form` and `redux-form-material-ui`. I have a `Field` that is type number and I want to set the min and max values on the  tag. I've tried both `inputProps` and min/max and neither seem to do what I want. I looked at the source code and don't see an obvious way to do this. Is it possible, and if so, how?

Here is my JSX showing things I've tried.

```
<Field
  name="maxNodeSelectedCount"
  component={TextField}
  label="Max Node Selected Count"
  type="number"
  inputProps={{ min: 0, max: 10 }}
  min={11}
  max={20}
  format={formatOption}
  normalize={normalizeOption}
  {...propertyFieldDefaults}
/>
```

Here is what the DOM looks like:

```
<input type="number" class="MuiInput-input-346 MuiInput-inputSingleline-349 MuiInput-inputDense-347" value="-3" name="options.maxNodeSelectedCount">
```

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The redux-form [Field](https://redux-form.com/7.2.0/docs/api/field.md/) will pass props through to the component:

> All other props will be passed along to the element generated by the component prop.

The [TextField](https://material-ui-next.com/api/text-field/) has a property named `InputProps` which can be used to pass props to the [Input](https://material-ui-next.com/api/input/) component it renders.  This is also true if you're using `redux-form-material-ui`.  Its TextField is simply a wrapper for the material-ui component.

The material-ui `Input` component has a property named `inputProps`  which can be used to pass props to the `input` element it renders.

**Ok, so what do I do?**

You need to pass props all the way through, from `Field`,  to `TextField`, to `Input`, to the `input` element.

So if we set `InputProps` on Field, it will be passed to TextField, which will pass it to the `Input` component.  If the object we pass contains an inner `inputProps` (intentional lowercase 'i'), the Input component will pass it to the `input` element.

**A game of hot-proptato:**

Basically, define an `inputProps` object within `InputProps` and apply it to `Field`:

```
<Field
    name="maxNodeSelectedCount"
    component={TextField}
    label="Max Node Selected Count"
    type="number"
    InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 } }}
    format={formatOption}
    normalize={normalizeOption}
    {...propertyFieldDefaults}
  />
```

- Field passes InputProps to `TextField`
- TextField passes the contents of InputProps to the `Input` component
- Input passed the contents of inputProps to the `input` element

**There is a caveat with this:**

The [current implementation of TextField](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/src/TextField/TextField.js) sets its own value for `inputProps` so that the `inputClassName` is applied to the `input` element.

By handing your own value of inputProps to TextField, you will overwrite the version applied by TextField, leaving `inputClassName` unset.  If are using `inputClassName` you will need to include it in the inner `inputProps` object.

**EDIT:** I have submitted an [issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/9508) and [pull request](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/pull/9509) to address this caveat in a future release.

Comment: Adding the props like this didn't work either:

props={{ InputProps: { min: 0, max: 10 } }}

Now TextField is from redux-form-material-ui and not material-ui and I don't know if that matters.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my answer.  The change from `inputProps` to `InputProps` is a breaking change [relased with 1.0.0-beta.23](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.23).

Comment: Thanks Ken for your help but I'm still having no luck. So do you think with beta 23 that InputProps should work? I even put a data property and nothing of these show up in the <input> DOM. `InputProps={{ min: 0, max: 10, 'data-action': 'Hello' }}` is rendering as `<input type="number" class="MuiInput-input-246 MuiInput-inputSingleline-249 MuiInput-inputDense-247" value="" name="options.maxNodeSelectedCount">`. I'm new to React and wondering if there is an online fiddle/sandbox that I can import my libraries to show the problem online?

Comment: @MikeSuiter Just updated the answer.  I missed the fact that `Input` and `input` are different!   TextField wraps Input, which is another material-ui component that wraps the actual `input` DOM element.

Comment: @MikeSuiter glad to help.  I just submitted a PR to address the issue I've mentioned.

Answer (score 81):

Simply use your *inputprops* well

```
<TextField 
    type="number"
    InputProps={{
        inputProps: { 
            max: 100, min: 10 
        }
    }}
    label="what ever"
/>
```

notice the upper and lower case in the inputprops

**credit to Ken Gregory**

Comment: `}` is missing after min : 10

Comment: <TextField 
    type="number"
    InputProps={{
        inputProps: { 
            max: 100, min: 10 
        }
    }}
    label="what ever">
</TextField>

Comment: @Karan, sorry I don't get you, what do you mean?

Comment: Jesus this is insaleny complicated for something so simple. Thanks for the working solution though.

Comment: I'm happy to help

Comment: @Lev you don't have to pass `inputProps` inside `InputProps`. Just pass it directly to the `TextField`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67072685/9449426) answer.

Comment: However, users can still enter values beyond the allowed range

Answer (score 27):

You can use `inputProps` to apply any attributes to the native `input` element, including `min` and `max`.

```html
<TextField type="number" inputProps={{ min: 4, max: 10 }} />
```

Please note that the `min`/`max` attributes do not prevent the user from typing invalid values in the `TextField`. To restrict what the user can type, you can validate the value by adding `onChange` handler like below:

```js
const min = 0;
const max = 10;

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<number>();

  return (
    <div>
      <TextField
        type="number"
        inputProps={{ min, max }}
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => {
          var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);

          if (value > max) value = max;
          if (value < min) value = min;

          setValue(value);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit 47798104/set-min-max-on-textfield-type-number]

Comment: This works really well and adds to the above accepted answer!

Answer (score 3):

Put `type` inside `InputProps`:

```
      <Field
        name="number"
        label="Number"
        component={TextField}
        InputProps={{
          inputProps: {
            type: 'number',
            min: 0, max: 25,
          },
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers didn't work for me.

Material UI has a section for 3rd party integration [here](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#integration-with-3rd-party-input-libraries)

It really does the job of writing only numbers and not allowing negatives.

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';

function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
    const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;
    
     return (
            <NumberFormat
                {...other}
                getInputRef={inputRef}
                allowNegative={false}
                onValueChange={(values) => {
                    onChange({
                        target: {
                            name: props.name,
                            value: values.value,
                        },
                    });
                }}
                isNumericString
            />
        );
}
    
<TextField
    label="react-number-format"
    value={values.numberformat}
    onChange={handleChange}
    name="numberformat"
    id="formatted-numberformat-input"
    InputProps={{
          inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
     }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using rect hook form you can validate things like so:

```js
import {Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
import {
  Box,
  TextField,
  FormHelperText,
  FormControl,

} from '@mui/material'
...
const {
  handleSubmit,
  control,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm({})
...
<Box mt={2}>
  <Controller
    name="weight"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      required: 'Veuillez choisir une réponse',
      validate: {
        weight: (value) =>
          value < 1 || value > 5
            ? 'Le poids doit etre entre 1 et 5'
            : undefined,
      },
    }}
    render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <TextField
          type="number"
          value={value}
          onChange={onChange}
          label="Poids"
          name="weight"
        />
      </FormControl>
    )}
  />
  <FormHelperText error={Boolean(errors.weight)}>
    {errors.weight?.message}
  </FormHelperText>
</Box>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**This will definitely work**

```
handleMobileNumber = (e) => {
 if (e.target.value.split("").length <= 10) {
  this.setState({
    mobileNumber: e.target.value,
  });
 }
};

<TextField
  label="Enter Mobile Number"
   variant="outlined"
   value={this.state.mobileNumber}
   onChange={this.handleMobileNumber}
   type="number"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case I wanted to prevent the user from adding very big or minus numbers in a MUI Textfield used for `minutes` or `hours` inputs.

My solution is the following: 
*In the MUI TextField*

```
  <TextField                                                            
    type={'number'}
    helperText={'minutes'}
    defaultValue={minutes}
    onChange={(e) => { checkMinutesValidity(e) }}
  />
```

*In the **checkMinutesValidity** function*

```
  const checkMinutesValidity = (event) => {
    if(event.target.value > 59){
      event.target.value = 59;
    }
    if(event.target.value < 0){
      event.target.value = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 type="number"
 InputProps={{
                inputProps: { 
                    max: 14 , min: 0.1 , step: "0.1"
                }
            }}
```

***you can enter decimal value as well using this***

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextField
            label="Username"
            id="outlined-start-adornment"
            variant="outlined"
            inputProps={{minlength:5, maxLength: 20}}
          />
```

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)