# React controlled component not resetting to an empty string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, controlled-component

I have a `<TextField>` component from Material UI that's supposed to allow a user to choose a numerical value. The field is for use on a medical product so we cannot have a default value that's displayed; rather, the value is initially an empty string and `onInput` we update it accordingly. The min/max props don't work as needed when passed to `InputProps`, so we manually check if the value passed is less than or equal to zero ('-' also evaluates to true here), and if so we reset the value to 1. However, when I try to instead reset the value to an empty string (i.e. clear the input), the actual state value changes, but the text displayed in the `TextField` component remains the same for some reason. If anyone knows why the text displayed is not clearing and what I could do to fix this, please let me know!

Code below:

```
<TextField
    disabled={!!requirement.id}
    type="number"
    value={requirement.val}
    variant="outlined"
    InputProps={{ inputProps: { min: 1, max: 1000000 } }}
    placeholder={'Title!'}
    onInput={(e) =>
        handleRequirementChange(
        Number(e.target.value),
        index
       )}
/>

  const handleRequirementChange = (val, index) => {
    const requirement = [...requirement]
    if (val <= 0) val = 1
    requirement[index] = val
    setRequirement(requirement)
  }
```

Comment: Questions: 1) Is it normal for `InputProps` to have an `inputProps` property? It's been a while since I've used MUI, but this strikes me as odd and I can't help wondering if that's why your min/max props don't work. 2) What is `nw`? 3) Is `requirement` an array or an object? You seem to treat it as both.

Comment: If by reset you mean to set a null value, TextField does not allow it. 
you can use like this for TextField value.   value={value || ""}

Comment: Where does the `nw` come from in your arrow function? That's what you `setRequirement` to. Is it an object with a .val property?

Comment: @ray 1) Good question - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798104/set-min-max-on-textfield-type-number) for the logic there, 2) that's a typo! 3) `requirement` is an object, the edit should help clear that up. @Brenton `nw` was a typo sorry. @Mahir I want to set it to an empty string - the only problem is that the empty string is not being displayed in the actual `<TextField>`.