# Restrict the number input to accept value from 0 to 100

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Number input component from MUI with Increment and Decrement buttons to increase and decrease the numbers.

If there a way to restrict the input to accept values only from **0 to 100** ?

And also how to reduce the width of the whole component ? because when I use the width component it reduces the inner input text field but buttons and my special characters are not getting adjusted.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-awmssq?file=Demo.js

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798104/set-min-max-on-textfield-type-number

Answer (score 1):

In Input type Number there is bit complicated in Input props. so Please onInput props like this for min and max value use like this

```
    const InputMaster = ({
      maxValue,
      minusAccepted,
      minValue,
      ...rest
    }) => {
    return (
      <TextField
        onInput={(e) => {
          if (type === 'number') {
            // Allow digits and a single decimal point
            e.target.value = minusAccepted ? e.target.value.replace(/[^-0-9.]/g, '') : e.target.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

            // Ensure that there is at most one decimal point
            const decimalCount = (e.target.value.match(/\./g) || []).length;
            if (decimalCount > 1) {
              e.target.value = e.target.value.slice(0, e.target.value.lastIndexOf('.'));
            }

            // Convert the input value to a number
            const numericValue = parseFloat(e.target.value);

            // Check if the numeric value exceeds the maxValue prop
            if (!isNaN(numericValue) && maxValue !== undefined && numericValue > maxValue) {
              e.target.value = maxValue.toString();
            }
            if (!isNaN(numericValue) && minValue !== undefined && numericValue < minValue) {
              e.target.value = minValue.toString();
            }
          }
        }}
    />
   );
```